# SQL - Select between 3 tables

Tags: sql, database

I have 3 tables:

```
hosts (host_id, name, address, template_id);
hostgroup (hostgroup_id, name);
hosts_hostgroup (a, b);
```

The first table keeps all the hosts, the second one all the groups and the last one says which group belong each host.

Note that `hosts_hostgroup` has two different column names `a` and `b`.

Which is the Query to give me the hosts that belong to some group?

Comment: Why not have a 'hostgroup_id' column in your 'hosts' table? Why the need for the extra 'hosts_hostgroup' table?

Comment: @Bernard, hosts can be in >1 group

Comment: @AJ: Perhaps, but this wasn't specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT h.*
FROM hosts h 
INNER JOIN hosts_hostgroup hg ON hg.host_id = h.host_id
INNER JOIN hostgroup g ON g.hostgroup_id = hg.hostgroup_id
WHERE g.name = 'mygroupname'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT hosts.* FROM hosts
INNER JOIN hosts_hostgroup ON hosts.host_id=hosts_hostgroup.a
WHERE hosts_hostgroup.b=(some id);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. And if in the table hosts_hostgroup the columns hostgroup_id and host_id where like a and b? hosts_hostgroup (a,b);

Comment: what is "a" and what is "b"?  does "a" hold host_id values or hostgroup_id values?  likewise, which values are stored in "b"?  Also, **why use names "a" and "b"** when all of your other identifiers have a meaningful naming convention?

Comment: yes, a and b hold the same values form host_id and hostgroup_id ... just with different names!

Comment: updated my answer based on the correct column names you specified.